# Reactjs private route always take me on first route after page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, routes, react-router

I am new on reactjs and stuck in a scenario like when I login the application using credentials and lands on the dashboard page, after when I navigate to some other page like List page from dashboard and try to refresh the page on list page it take me back to dashboard page instead to stay on the current page i.e List page.

Below is the Route Page of my code.

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/forgotPassword" component={ForgotPassword} />
          <Route exact path="/changePassword" component={ChangePassword} />
          <PrivateRoutes exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
          <PrivateRoutes exact path="/list" component={List} />
          <PrivateRoutes exact path="/listDetails/:id" component={ListDetails} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

And Private route code is

```
class PrivateRoute extends Component {
  render() {
    let componentData = '';
    componentData = <div><SideNavigation /> <Route render={() => <this.props.component {...this.props} />} /> </div>;
    return componentData;
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to pass the isAuthenticated prop yourself. It's not handled by react router.

Comment: Thanks @Lahiru for reply....Yes I used redux for that and its working fine...